# Can spark streaming cluster be used to buffer data?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

This is my first time of using Spark streaming. We have a use case where, we are streaming 10KB files into spark stream cluster which are being processed. We also want to merge these 10 KB incoming documents to a file till its size reaches 30 MB and then upload that RDD to S3.

I imagine as follows,

1. We will cache RDD which will be constantly appended with incoming 10 KB documents.
2. Before append operation, if size of current cached RDD is 30 MB, it will upload it to S3 and create new RDD and append to it and cache it with same name, otherwise will simply append to existing cache.

Can this approach work? Please correct if my understanding of spark streaming cache is incorrect here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stateful Transformations` methods in Spark Streaming (`updateStateByKey` and `mapWithState`)

```
val sparkContext = new SparkContext()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Duration(4000))
ssc.checkpoint("path/to/persistent/storage")
```

Otherwise process the data (In batch interval) and save it to S3 bucket. After that run separate job to merge the data.